# I want to build JSON object in android from a table in mysql database contains a foreign key?

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, foreign-key-relationship

I need some help.

What I need to do basically, it's a simple mapping relation (FK) between to databases and bring this as JSON (using java).

For example, how can i change this script:

```
        JSONArray ja=new JSONArray(jsonData);

        JSONObject jo=null;

        for(int i=0;i<ja.length();i++)
        {
            jo=ja.getJSONObject(i);

            int id=jo.getInt("0");
            int course_id=jo.getInt("4");// it is an a primary key for another table

            String hour=jo.getString("2");
       }
```

> Table: Schedule  { schedule_id : primary key course_id : foreign key
>   ,hour}
>
> Table : Course  {course_id : primary key course_name  }

Comment: what Json library are you using?

Comment: import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

Comment: Ok, but sorry I dont get what's your target

Comment: nothing wrong, but i want to build a json object from a table contains a foreign key  like:  int course=jo.getInt("4");int trainer=jo.getInt("6");  how can i get to the values of the another table with this two primary keys.

Comment: Well outside for, create a JsonObject where to add your information at every iteration

Comment: have you an example please?

Comment: Can you add an example of your primary keys and structure of tables?

Comment: table : schedule{ primary key : schedule_id, course_id: foreign key} table : course {primary key: course_id}

Comment: Just edit your question for god sake

Comment: it is done. thank you

Comment: is the data for both tables inside the JSONArray?

Comment: yes the data for both tables inside the JSONArray